# Grouping Elements of Lists Within a List by Index

Tags: python, list

I am trying to take a list of lists, and return a list of lists which contain each element at an index of the original list of lists. I know that that's badly worded. Here's an example.

Say I have the following list of lists:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

I want to get another list of lists, in which each list is a list of each elements at a specific index. For example:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]] becomes [[1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,6,9]]
```

So the first list in the returned list, contains all of the elements at the first index of each of the original list, and so on. I'm stuck, and have no idea how this could be done. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: That's commonly called transposing or rotating.

Comment: @delnan: I'd rather not call it rotating. IMO rotating is `mylist = mylist[1:] + mylist[:1]` (left) or `mylist = mylist[-1:] + mylist[:-1]` (right).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> [list(t) for t in zip(*[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])]
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: I feel really stupid, having missed a built-in that does exactly that. In my defense, I've never had to use something like it before. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

perhaps an easy way wiould be:

```
a=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
b=zip(*a)
```

b will be equal to [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)].
hopes this helps

Comment: N.B: This list contains tuples, rather than lists in Python 2.x and a `zip` object in Python 3.x. This is probably okay, but worth noting.

Comment: yes, and this is perhaps sufficient. Dan D. solution is already giving the complete solution with lists. Your solution is also nice using arrays, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Dan D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483114/grouping-elements-of-lists-within-a-list-by-index/6483122#6483122) is correct and will work in Python 2.*x* and Python 3.*x*.

If you're doing lots of matrix operations, not just transposition, it's worth considering [Numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html#numpy.swapaxes) at this juncture:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
>>> np.swapaxes(x, 0, 1)
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Or, more simply, as per the comments, use [`numpy.transpose()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html):

```
>>> np.transpose(x)
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Comment: @katrielalex: Because I forgot it was there! Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `zip(*lists)` approach, you could also use a list comprehension:

```
[[l[i] for l in lists] for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: Or `[[l[i] for l in lists] for i in range(len(lists))]` to remove the hard-coded three.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to simply transpose your matrix -e.g. to get new matrix where rows are cols from initial matrix while columns equal to the initial matrix rows values then you can use:

```
initMatr = [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9]
           ]
map(list, zip(*initMatr))


>>> [
     [1,4,7],
     [2,5,8],
     [3,6,9]
    ]
```

OR in case you want to rotate matrix left then:

```
map(list, zip(*map(lambda x: x[::-1], initMatr)

>>> [
       [3,6,9],
       [2,5,8],
       [1,4,7]       
    ]
```